# How to pass output values from one service task to other service task

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to pass some output values from one service task to other service task.  Here i can able to call java class from service task and able to run the program but the program output is displayed on command prompt. I need to pass the output values to other service task to continue the flow. If there is any suggestions means please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use process variables

```
delegateExecution.setVariable("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call a java class in service task and set output value into a global  variable then in other service task you can read stored value from that variable.

```
runtimeService.setVariable(executionId,variableName,variableValue);

runtimeService.getVariable(processId,variableName);
```